# BigQuery - How to go beyond 10'000 columns?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to find a way to query a very large (>100k columns) and sparse table (>99% sparsity) via BigQuery, but I hit the limit of 10'000 columns [1].
Is there any way to circumvent this limitation, e.g. by querying an external BigTable [2] or Storage (Avro/Parquet/...) [3] ?

Thanks for your support !

References

[1] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas

[2] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-bigtable

[3] https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-cloud-storage

Comment: +1 To the answer of @JohnHarley. If your data meets the appropriate query patterns you can use BigTable instead, it will provide no limitations in the number of columns or rows you need to manage, and from the storage point of view it will be a perfect fit for such a sparse table.

Comment: @jccampanero: Thanks. Can then BigTable be queried by BigQuery as an external table and without this limitation ?

Comment: Hi @py-r. That is indeed an interesting question. BigQuery and BigTable are completely different models. In BigQuery you use SQL like queries, whereas in BigTable all the information, every row in your table, is structured around a key and you should use that key for querying your data. You must define the key properly to improve the performance of your queries. Ideally, you should use the BigTable provided mechanisms to query the information. But, at first glance, you [can use BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-bigtable#permanent-tables) to query am underlying BigTable.

Comment: I said at first glance and not yes because be aware that the limitation of 10000 columns still is in place, both at table definition and query results level. This fact makes me think that in your specific use case, you won't be able to query BigTable with BigQuery either, but honestly I am not aware to provide you a definitive answer.

Comment: @jccampanero: Thanks. I’d be glad to get gcloud’s team view on this. Anyone ?

Comment: You are welcome @py-r. I am in fact GCP Professional Architect but as I said, your question is interesting. I hope anyone in the GCP team gives you a better answer

Comment: @gcloud: Any idea if this limit still exists when querying an external BigTable ?

Comment: Hi @py-r. Have your tried to query QB table by joining more than 2 columns ? As a work around you can try concatenation more columns if it works for your solution and BQ allow it. So plz try this out also.

Comment: @Vibhor : Thanks for your input. What do you mean by "joining more than 2 columns" ? Concatenate them ?

Comment: Yes, have you tried concatenating option ?

Comment: I want granular value storage for precise and efficient queries while keeping clear context. Working with concatenation would come with REGEX and LIKE clauses, not to speak about concatenated column names with no business meaning. In short, not an acceptable option for data that is heavily used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit of 10,000 columns per table is a [documented](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas) limitation fo internal tables.

However, by creating a [temporary or permanent external table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-bigtable#bq) from BigTable, it is possible to use BigQuery beyond this limit - I did a test with 20'000 columns using the BigTable native schema, i.e. without explicit column definition in the table definition file - though at the expense of a [challenging SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-bigtable?_ga=2.237422979.-2086912879.1607804587#bq_1) for simple filters like :

```
bq query \
-- use_legacy_sql=true \
-- external_table_definition=<my_bigtable>::<my_table_definition>.json \
'
select count(1) from <my_bigtable>
OMIT RECORD
IF NOT SOME(cf.column.name = "col19997" AND cf.column.cell.value = "foo")
'
```

To simplify this, the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/external-data-bigtable?_ga=2.237422979.-2086912879.1607804587#bq_1) explains how to write an explicit definition of the columns in the table definition file, which can be me made on a subset of the columns one wants to filter:

```
...
columns = [{"qualifierString": "col19997", "type": "STRING"}, ...]
...
```

One can then apply some simple SQL:

```
bq query \
--use_legacy_sql=false \
...
where cf.col19997.cell.value ="foo"
...
```

But doing so on the 20'000 columns leads to the following error (limit related ?). Hence, a handy solution seems to be to specify only the columns in the file that one wants to filter against with easy SQL.

`Too many total leaf fields: 20002`

Answer (score 2):

10,000 columns per table is a [documented](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas) limitation. No, there is no option to change this limitation.

Comment: Thanks. Would you know other similar DWH systems that would support this use case ?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know of one. BigQuery is one of the best. For a SQL based database, 10,000 columns is huge.

Comment: @gcloud: Any idea if this limit still exists when querying an external BigTable ?